# How to increase the font size of the command line in vimperator / pentadactyl?

Tags: vimperator, pentadactyl, dotfiles

What to I insert into my `.vimperatorrc` to make the font size of the command line bigger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set font sizes in css. These css settings can be applied with the `hi[ghlight]` command. E. g.:

```
:hi CmdLine -append font-size:16px
```

To view a list of all settings that are possible to change with the highlight command, see `:help :hi`.

For example, you would most likely also like to increase the size of the descriptions of the completion items too. This can be done with the following setting:

```
:hi CompDesc -append font-size:16px
```

To use these automatically on startup, just open the file `~/.vimperatorrc` and add them there, without the leading colon.